# How disable "last password you remember" of Google, after knowing that someone has my password?

Tags: passwords, google, password-reset

I have received this email from Google:

```
Someone just used your password to try to sign in to your Google Account xxxxxx@gmail.com.
Details:
     Sunday, July 9, 2017 11:27 AM (France Time) 
     ******, France
Google stopped this sign-in attempt, but you should review your recently used devices
```

Google was right! Someone has my password and tried to login to my account.

I changed my password, but I wonder whether the attacker can use "*Enter the last password you remember*" option of the Google to regain her access to my account? Can I disable this option for my account?

Comment: Change your password more than 3 times and by this way the last password will change that known by attacker.

Comment: Does Google accept only last 3 password?

Answer (score 2):

To reset the password there are several ways. But at the end google send a **SMS** message to confirm the reset.

If you have the **correct phone number** in your google profile, the attacker can't access to your account with the old password.

To add another security you can activate the [2 Factor Authentication](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839?hl=en)

Comment: Which is actually quite a strange move from Google as far as I'm concerned because 2FA by sending an SMS is the most insecure for of Multi Factor Authentication.
It is quite easy to read SMS's as a man in the middle. And there are very prominent examples:
https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2019/09/06/twitter-slaps-back-sms-texting-after-jack-hijacking/